# Python - Guessing a number game: no output

Tags: python, infinite-loop, indentation, python-3.10

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to build a guessing a number game but not sure why the console doesn't display anything?!

```
import random

    game_random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    game_active = True  
    
    
    while game_active:  
      game_start_message = "guess a number between 1 and 100"
      user_guess = int(input()) 
    if user_guess == game_random_number:
      print("You guessed it correctly")
      game_active = False
    elif user_guess < game_random_number:
      print("Too low guess again")
    else:
      print("Too high, guess again")
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Specifically the if/elif/else needs to be further indented by two spaces.

Comment: I agree with @mozway It looks like you need to indent your `if` statements

Comment: It works fine with the correct indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine with the correct indentation. You otherwise fall in an infinite loop where you do nothing but request user to input a number.

```
import random

game_random_number = 42 # just for the test
game_active = True  
    
    
while game_active:  
    game_start_message = "guess a number between 1 and 100"
    user_guess = int(input()) 
    if user_guess == game_random_number:
        print("You guessed it correctly")
        game_active = False
    elif user_guess < game_random_number:
        print("Too low guess again")
    else:
        print("Too high, guess again")
```

example:

```
1
Too low guess again
2
Too low guess again
50
Too high, guess again
42
You guessed it correctly
```

*NB. `game_start_message = "guess a number between 1 and 100"` doesn't do anything. Maybe you should rather print this string before the loop?*

Answer (score 1):

You did your indentation wrong, causing your if...elif...else structure to fall outside of the while loop, since that while loop never stops, it will keep asking for user inputs and never actually print anything else

Here is your code with the correct indentation:

```
import random

game_random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
game_active = True  

while game_active:  
    game_start_message = "guess a number between 1 and 100"
    user_guess = int(input())

    if user_guess == game_random_number:
        print("You guessed it correctly")
        game_active = False
    elif user_guess < game_random_number:
        print("Too low guess again")
    else:
        print("Too high, guess again")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply...I was used to JS and auto indentation, although in JS indentation isn't a problem in terms of breaking the code...But in Python its really a pain...Any suggestions on any tool for VS Code to help with identation? Much appreciated

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Python does have auto indentation in VSC by default, the issue however is that it doesnt have { } to help the auto indenter know what you meant. Therefore it wouldnt rly be possible to have something like this, as it cant possibly predict that you didnt mean to put those if statement outside the while loop

Comment: Ye i'm with you...would you reccomend pyCharm or any other IDE/editor that makes working with python more smooth? Once again many thanks

Comment: @AndreCastro I'd say that pycharm is a better experience for python programming, however vscode is nowhere near 'bad'. Use whatever you feel comfortable with